# How to build a comparison that would result in a new md5sum if conditions are met

Tags: shell-script

Ubuntu 16.04 - trying to fine tune

Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

# if the .md5sum file doesn't exists
# or if the .md5sum file exists && doesn't match, recreate it
# but if the .md5sum file exists && matches then break and log

csvfile=inventory.csv

if [ ! -f .md5sum ] || [ -f .md5sum ] && [ ! md5sum -c .md5sum >/dev/null ]; then
   md5sum "$csvfile" > .md5sum
else
   echo "$csvfile file matched md5sum ..."
   break
fi
```

I am having issues with building the conditional statement that would result in a new .md5sum. I am trying to find what part of the conditional statement is wrong and this is what shellcheck tells me.

```
root@me ~ # shellcheck run.sh

In run.sh line 8:
if [ ! -f .md5sum ] || [ -f .md5sum ] && [ ! md5sum -c .md5sum >/dev/null ]; then
^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this if expression.
                                         ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this test expression.
                                                               ^-- SC1072: Expected "]". Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

I can do the entire process with a few comparisons but I think I'll achieve a faster and cleaner script if I joined the comparisons.

I also checked the code by Jesse_P

```
#!/bin/bash

csvfile=inventory.csv

echo "hello" > inventory.csv
md5sum "$csvfile" > .md5sum
echo "well hello" > inventory.cvs

if [[ ! -f .md5sum ]] || [[ -f .md5sum && ! md5sum -c .md5sum >/dev/null ]]; then
        echo "All conditiions have been met to generate a new md5sum for inventory.csv ..."
        md5sum inventory.csv > .mds5sum
fi
exit 0
```

Then I used shellcheck

```
root@0003 ~ # shellcheck run.sh
    In run.sh line 8:
    if [[ ! -f .md5sum ]] || [[ -f .md5sum && ! md5sum -c .md5sum >/dev/null ]]; then
    ^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this if expression.
                             ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this test expression.
                                                                  ^-- SC1072: Expected "]". Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

Comment: `if [ ! -f .md5sum ] || ! md5sum -c .md5sum >/dev/null; then`

Comment: `if [[ ! -f .md5sum ]] || [[ -f .md5sum && ! md5sum -c .md5sum >/dev/null ]]; then`

Comment: @Jesse_b  I added your comment to my question with shellcheck results.

Comment: @needtoknow: Shellcheck isn't always right.  What I wrote _should_ work but like shellcheck I also wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Proper code

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -f .md5sum ] || [ -f .md5sum ] && ! md5sum -c .md5sum > /dev/null
then
    echo "All conditions have been met to generate a new md5sum for inventory.csv ..."
    md5sum inventory.csv > .mds5sum
fi
```

## Parsing

```
[ ! -f .md5sum ]
[ -f .md5sum ]
```

These are ordinary `test` commands, so POSIX-ly `[...]`, no need for double brackets.

```
! md5sum -c .md5sum > /dev/null
```

This is NOT a `test` command, so NO brackets around it.

## Notes

1. No need for `bash`, `sh` will do in this script. I can only recommend to stick with POSIX shell (`sh`) as long as you can for portability purposes.
2. `md5sum` has been superseded, e.g. with `sha512sum`. No hashing algorithm is perfect, but `md5sum` is known not to be collision-resistant especially. I can only recommend to use `sha512sum` as long as you don't need extra short hash.
3. Read some more about the [test command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test).
4. Optionally, read some more about [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

Comment: Your explanation was fantastic. Me hats off to ya mate.